# How can I create multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I was watching a tutorial video that has this peace of code:

```
  if ( isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    if ( !isset ($_SESSION['chats']) ) $_SESSION['chats'] = Array();
    $_SESSION['chats'] [] = array($_POST['message'], date(DATE_RFC2822));
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
  }
```

But I am confused about this line:

```
$_SESSION['chats'] [] = array($_POST['message'], date(DATE_RFC2822));
```

That I don't know what is the meaning of `= array($_POST['message'], date(DATE_RFC2822));` ? Is `$_SESSION` a two dimensional array? Or it's just a one dimension array with 2 elements? If it's one dimension array, how can I write a 2-D array?

Comment: @Dharman: Ok:, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to know what happens on each execution step of your code, it is best to use a debugger for this, e.g. XDebug. You can put a breakpoint and go line by line through your code and see the state of the variables.
[image]

Another way, would be to put a `var_export($_SESSION);` after that line and check the output:

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'chats' => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 'gdf',
            1 => 'Sat, 20 Apr 2019 21:08:26 +0100',
        )
    )
)
```

In your case the superglobal array `$_SESSION` contains an array inserted with a key 'chats' which contains another array of items i.e. `array($_POST['message'], date(DATE_RFC2822))`.

Yes, `$_SESSION` in your example will be a multi-dimensional array (3-D). To create a multi-dimensional array in PHP, one needs to enter another array as an element of the outer array. Exactly as you have done in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. $_SESSION['chats'] is an array containing multiple arrays with each a message and a date. In PHP i sometimes like to ouput array structures to see what is really happening. You should do something like this to check the array tree (just for training without the use of external plugins like XDebug):

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['chats']); exit();
```

Output will look something like this which is more readable. Once you worked with enough arrays you won't need this anymore.

```
[chats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => message
                [1] => Sat, 20 Apr 2019 13:10:09 -0700
            )

    )
```